# Ruby - Convert encoded character to actual UTF-8 character

Tags: ruby, encoding, filenames, encode

I am having difficulty converting UTF-8 byte characters into their actual UTF-8 characters.

I have a downloaded image file called `J%C3%83%C2%A4germeister.jpg` and I need to have the proper encoding so that the name is: `JÃgermeister.jpg`

Is there any quick way to convert these to the actual accent chars in Ruby?

I have only managed to `gsub` each `"%C3%83"` to the actual letter, but they all have to be done separately so it takes many lines of code.

I have tried:

```
filename = filename.force_encoding('utf-8')
```

But nothing changes.

Comment: You can try: `CGI::unescape('J%C3%83%C2%A4germeister.jpg')`

Comment: This question was marked as a duplicate but the answer in the duplication question did not work for me. Your answer above worked.